Azure - assign Hibernate-Only role to a single user in Azure Portal
I'm supporting an NGO and we are using the Microsoft-Azure-Sponsorship program.
We have a Windows 10 system for graphic rendering. But it would exceed our budget to run it all the time. As of my understanding, there is an option to put a system into hibernate state within Azure Portal when not used and thus reducing costs. But i dont want to give admin rights to the user of the Windows 10 system.
How can i give a specific user the right to only set a system to hibernate in Azure Portal and restart the system as well?
Any option to do this via a script running on a webserver (I have a Linux system in the same environment as well that is already running az snapshot commands with the related resource group)?
I have to admit, that I'm new to Azure Portal - any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance
Pengo
Assing role in Azure Portal - but that didnt work for Hibernate only

Does the user who needs to hibernate/restart the VM already have an Azure account, and if so, what roles or permissions do they currently have?


Azure - assign Hibernate-Only role to a single user in Azure

For this you need to create a custom role for VM hibernate.
Please refer this Msdoc for better understanding about how to create a custom role in azure.
Follow the below steps to create the custom role in your subscription.

Go to your azure subscription - > Access control(IAM) - > Add custom role -> Give the name -> add the required permissions -> Assign the scope -> hit review+create.





After creating the custom role, you can add this role to your specific resource.
Here I've added this role to a resource group.


click on select member and add the required user.


This is how you can limit the specific user's access to only starting, stopping, and hibernating the VM without giving them full administrative rights.
